# What is the complexity of these functions with explanation?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory

i would like to know how to find the complexity of these functions using T(n) .. and stuff like this .. Because i can only Guess.

 **First Function :**

```
int f(int n)
{ 
 if (n == 1)
      return 1 ;
  return 1 + f(f(n-1));
 }
```

Time&Space complexity ??

**Second Function :**

time&space Complexity of Function f() ??? :

```
void f(int n)
{
  int i ;
  if(n < 2) return ;
   for(i = 0 ; i < n/2 , i+= 5)
       printf("*");
   g(n/3);
   g(n/3);
 }


void g(int n)
   {
      int i ;
      for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
         printf("?") ;
      f(3*n/2);
   }
```

**Many Thanks :)**

Comment: You can not only guess, what about measure it for different values and than  have an educated guess after locking at the graphs or try to interpolate the findings with different types of functions?

Comment: Hello to the stackexchange network. People are expected to show a quantum of effort they put into figuring out their problems here. What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @G.Bach 
I tried to solve it using asthmatics equations like T(n) .. but i have no idea how to continue

Comment: @AmeenAli Whether you get stuck or not is really not a problem - just remember to describe as concise as you can what you did and why you got stuck; the clearer you describe why you got stuck, the better people will be able to help you learn something instead of just posting solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may surprise you, but the second one is easier to start with. O_o ikr

---

Second function:

`g(n) = n + f(3n/2)`, `f(n) = n/10 + 2g(n/3)`. Therefore `f(n) = 21n/10 + 2f(n/2)`.

Substitute `n = 2^m`, therefore `f(2^m) = 21(2^m)/10 + 2f(2^(m-1)) = 2*21(2^m)/10 + 4f(2^(m-2))` etc...

The first term sums to `m*21(2^m)/10`, which may be obvious to you.

The second term (with the f()) grows geometrically; now `f(1) = 1` (as there is only 1 operation), so if you expand to the last term you will find this term is `2^m * f(1) = 2^m`. Therefore the total complexity of `f` is `f(2^m) = m*21(2^m)/10 + 2^m`, or `f(n) = n(2.1*log(n) + 1)`, where `log` is base-2 logarithm.

**Thus `f(n)` is `O(n log(n))`.**

---

First function:

Ok I'll be honest I didn't know how to start, but I tested the code in C++ and the result is exactly `f(n) = n`.

Proof by induction:

- Suppose `f(n) = n`, then `f(n + 1) = 1 + f(f(n)) = n + 1`. Thus if true for n then also true for n + 1
- Now `f(1) = 1` obviously. Therefore it's true for 2, and for 3, 4, 5 ... and so on.

Therefore by mathematical induction, `f(n) = n`.

Now for the time complexity bit. Since `f(n)` returns `n`, the outer call in the nested `f(f(n-1))` will effectively be a second call, as the argument is the same: `f(n-1); f(n-1);`. Thus `T(n) = 2*T(n-1)` and therefore `T(n) = 2^n`. **`O(2^n)`**.

Comment: the second function is n*log(n) thanks!!
the first one is 2^n :((

Comment: @AmeenAli fixed :) sry i forgot the time complexity thing somehow